# Create duplicate values when combining dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes like so:

df1

| Name | Animal |
| --- | --- |
| John | Dog |
| John | Cat |
| John | Horse |
| Mary | Dog |
| Mary | Cat |
| Mary | Horse |

df2

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| John | Blue |
| Mary | Red |

I would like to merge them such that:

df3

| Name | Animal | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Dog | Blue |
| John | Cat | Blue |
| John | Horse | Blue |
| Mary | Dog | Red |
| Mary | Cat | Red |
| Mary | Horse | Red |

What would be the clearest way to go about this? I've tried multiple permutations of concat(), append(), merge(), and join() functions to no avail. I'm sure it has to be something simple, but most of the literature around this focuses on subsetting and eliminating duplicates, but not adding them.

Comment: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Name')` I think would get you 95% of the way of the there (just an extra column you'll have to drop).

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Color'] = df['Name'].map(df2.set_index(['Name'])['Color'])
```

```
    Name    Animal  Color
0   John    Dog     Blue
1   John    Cat     Blue
2   John    Horse   Blue
3   Mary    Dog     Red
4   Mary    Cat     Red
5   Mary    Horse   Red
```